# State pattern using NHibernate and FluentMapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, domain-driven-design

In our appliacion, we are using state pattern, for our entities. We have a problem, with mapping the state to the database value. Our current solution works, but does not support IQueryable  (from hibernate), thus forcing us to call .ToList() in repositories.

Here is our entity:

```
public class Gap 
{
    [ommited]

    public virtual IGapState State { get; protected set; }
    public virtual IGapState PreviousState { get; protected set; }
}
```

Currently, our mapping for IGapState looks like this:

```
public class GapMap : ClassMap<Gap> {
    [ommited]

    Map(x => x.State).CustomType<GapStateType>();
    Map(x => x.PreviousState).CustomType<GapPreviousStateType>()
}
```

And our custom type for this looks like this:

```
public class GapStateType : ICompositeUserType
{
    public bool IsMutable => false;
    public virtual string[] PropertyNames => new string[1] { "State" };
    public IType[] PropertyTypes => new IType[1] { NHibernateUtil.Int32 };
    public Type ReturnedClass => typeof(IGapState);
    public object Assemble(object cached, ISessionImplementor session, object owner) => cached;
    public object DeepCopy(object value) => value;
    public object Disassemble(object value, ISessionImplementor session) => value;
    public new bool Equals(object x, object y) => object.Equals(x, y);
    public int GetHashCode(object x) => x.GetHashCode();
    public object GetPropertyValue(object component, int property)
    {
        IGapState state = (IGapState)component;
        return state.Discriminator;
    }

    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader dr, string[] names, ISessionImplementor session, object owner)
    {
        State state = (State)NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeGet(dr, names[0]);
        switch (state)
        {
            case State.New:
                return new New();
            case State.InProgress:
                return new InProgress();
            case State.TicketClosedWaitingForEvidence:
                return new TicketClosedWaitingForEvidence();
            case State.EvidenceProvidedWaitingForTicketClosure:
                return new EvidenceProvidedWaitingForTicketClosure();
            case State.EvidenceProvidedWaitingForTicketAssigment:
                return new EvidenceProvidedWaitingForTicketAssigment();
            case State.FalsePositiveWaitingForApproval:
                return new FalsePositiveWaitingForApproval();
            case State.FalsePositiveApproved:
                return new FalsePositiveApproved();
            case State.RiskStateWaitingForApproval:
                return new RiskStateWaitingForApproval();
            case State.RiskStateApproved:
                return new RiskStateApproved();
            case State.Closed:
                return new Closed();
            default:
                return new Null();
        }
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index, bool[] settable, ISessionImplementor session)
    {
        //State state = (State)value;
        //NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeSet(cmd, (int)state, index);
        IGapState state = (IGapState)value;
        NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeSet(cmd, (int)state.Discriminator, index);
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, ISessionImplementor session, object owner)
    {
        return target;
    }

    public void SetPropertyValue(object component, int property, object value)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Discriminator is an immutable object. SetPropertyValue isn't supported.");
    }
}
```

In repository we call

```
public IEnumerable<Gap> FindWatingForApprovalRisk()
{
    return FindAll().ToList().Where(x => x.State.Discriminator == State.RiskStateWaitingForApproval);
}
```

Which is all fine, until we don't have a large amount of entities. When we cut out ToList() and change return type to IQueryable we get the following exception:

```
could not resolve property: State.Discriminator of: 
Exprimo.CBA.Model.Entities.GapPortal.Gap 
[.Count[Exprimo.CBA.Model.Entities.GapPortal.Gap]
(.Where[Exprimo.CBA.Model.Entities.GapPortal.Gap]
(NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[Exprimo.CBA.Model.Entities.GapPortal.Gap], 
Quote((x, ) => (Equal(Convert(x.State.Discriminator), p1))), ), )]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate doesn't know what to do with x.State.Discriminator, because your mapping stops at x.State.

Try:

```
.Where(x => x.State == new RiskStateWaitingForApproval())
```